# Prove the following set is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need some help with part (b) of the question. Would appreciate feedback on whether my solution to part (a) is correct too.

For each  ∈ ℝ, define  = { +  ∶  ∈ ℤ}. Let  = { ∶  ∈ ℝ}.

(a) Prove that  is countable for every  ∈ ℝ.

(b) Prove that  is uncountable.

You may use without proof the fact that a set  is countable if and only if there is a sequence
0, 1, 2, … ∈  in which every element of  appears.

For part (a), I proved that for all  ∈ ℝ,  can be written in a sequence defined as below:

c2i = x - i

c2i+1 = x + i + 1

i.e.  = {x, x + 1, x - 1, x + 2, x - 2, x + 3, x - 3, ....}

For part (b), however, I am stuck on proving .
I believe it is probably something to do with cardinality of Unions? Since  is just a Union of 1, 2, 3 ...

However, in my current syllabus, one theorem I am taught is that:

 "Let A,B be countable infinite sets. Then A U B is countable."

Thank you for taking the time to read this and I appreciate all feedback! Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It would be preferable to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. You can [get started here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and a more complete reference [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: $[0,1)$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution on part a, the idea is correct, but there is a typo in $c_{2i}=x-i$.

For part (b): $[0,1)$ can be imbedded in $\mathscr{C}$ via the map $x\mapsto Ax$.

Let $x,y\in[0,1)$ with $Ax=Ay$, then there must be some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $x=y+k$. As $|x-y|<1$, thus $k=0$ and $x=y$.

This proves the injectivity.
$[0,1)$ is uncountable and so is $\mathscr{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

> Since  is just a Union of 1, 2, 3 ...

No!  is a set of sets, not a union of sets. The cardinality of  is just the number of sets it contains. Naively you might think that this is the same as the cardinality of $\{x:x\in\Bbb R\}$, which of course is just $\mathfrak{c}$. But there are duplications in there, so you have to be a bit careful.

Answer (score 0):

For $b)$ we have that $Ax$ is distinct between $A(0)$ and $A(1)$. Hence the cardinality is at least the same as the interval $(0,1)$, which we know is uncountable.